# cts:uris with namespace binding

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I have multiple XML documents stored in MarkLogic, my requirement is to get the URIs of the document when there is a specific element in it, all XMLs are stored with namespace in it.

sample XML from MarkLogic

```
<item xmlns="http://namespaces.test.org/namespaces/ab">
    <itemId>TestItem</itemId>
    <languageCode>EN</languageCode>
</item>
```

following query was executed with no result,

```
cts:uris((), (), cts:and-query(
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("itemId"), cts:true-query()))
)
```

looks like namespace is causing issue here, I am not sure how to specify the namespace in `cts:uris()`

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `itemId` element is in the `http://namespaces.test.org/namespaces/ab` namespace. The parent element `item` declares the namespace and doesn't use a namespace-prefix, so it's a little harder to see that at first.

Your element-query is looking for an `itemId` that isn't bound to any namespace, so it doesn't find anything.

In order to query for docs that have that `itemId` element, you need to construct a QName that includes the namespace:

```
declare namespace ab = "http://namespaces.test.org/namespaces/ab";

cts:uris((), (), cts:and-query(
  cts:element-query(xs:QName("ab:itemId"), cts:true-query()))
)
```